# xUnit Culture Aware Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core-2.0, data-annotations, xunit

I created a new xunit test project at Visual Studio 2017 a minute ago. The project contains xunit nuget package which is 2.3.1 version for net-core 2.0

I saw the usage of annotation at [xUnit Sample](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/master/UseCulture/UseCultureAttributeTests.cs);however, when I tried to use `UseCulture` annotation, I faced an error like this:

> The type or namespace name 'UseCultureAttribute' could not be found.

What am I missing?

```
[Fact, UseCulture("en-US")]
public void Test1()
{
    double a = 5.01;
    string aStr = a.ToString();

    Assert.Equal("5.01", aStr);
}
```

Comment: @JonathonChase, thanks for your comment. I searched a little bit and found `CulturedTheory` and `CulturedFact` (https://github.com/xunit/xunit/tree/master/test/test.utility/CultureAwareTesting) . However, these annotations do not work either. Do you know any good solution for culture aware testing?

Comment: Yeah, look at the second link I posted. It's the implementation code of a `UseCultureAttribute`. You should be able to just drop that into your project and proceed.

Comment: In my question, I posted the same link as well. However, I am wondering, if there is a built in solution or supported extensions (another nuget packages)?

Comment: I've created a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CultureAwareTesting.xUnit) which implements `CulturedTheory` and `CulturedFact`.
The GitHub project can be found [here](https://github.com/StefH/CultureAwareTesting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing I wasn't able to find this either in .NET Core 2.0.
Here's an example (based on the [link](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/main/UseCulture/UseCultureAttribute.cs) given in the comments to your question).
You just need to add the `xunit.core` nuget package to make this work.

My example sets it to `InvariantCulture` before the test (and reverts it afterwards), you could tweak this to your needed culture or use the more versatile option given in the [link](https://github.com/xunit/samples.xunit/blob/main/UseCulture/UseCultureAttribute.cs).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class UseInvariantCultureAttribute : BeforeAfterTestAttribute
{
    private CultureInfo originalCulture;
    private CultureInfo originalUICulture;

    public override void Before(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        this.originalCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        this.originalUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    }

    public override void After(MethodInfo methodUnderTest)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = this.originalCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = this.originalUICulture;
    }
}
```